# yarn v2/v3 has no outdated command?

Tags: yarn-v2

on `yarn outdated` in yarn `v2` or `v3` there is this error:

```
Usage Error: Couldn't find a script named "outdated".
```

I found an alternative with `yarn upgrade-interactive`, but then I need to install this plugin into the project, which is wanted to avoid. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok, I found an easy alternative  - using `npm`:

```
npm outdated
```

Comment: Now it's just `yarn plugin import interactive-tools` the first time, then `yarn upgrade-interactive`

Answer (score 8):

yarn v2 / v3 no longer has the outdated command, however you can add a plugin which will allow you to interactively update packages.

First add the plugin: `yarn plugin import interactive-tools` (for each project)

Then you can run `yarn upgrade-interactive`

[Link to documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/upgrade-interactive)

Example of plugin:

[image: Example of plugin]

Comment: Yarn 4 now supports the `yarn upgrade-interactive` command without the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

[Possibly relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/749). `yarn outdated` is gone, period.

[yarn-plugin-outdated](https://github.com/mskelton/yarn-plugin-outdated) is a community-built plugin which does the same thing. But this may not be what you are looking for, since it is a plugin after all.

If plain NPM packages are okay for you, then see [npm-check](https://github.com/dylang/npm-check), [npm-check-updates](https://github.com/raineorshine/npm-check-updates) and [check-outdated](https://github.com/jens-duttke/check-outdated). **Disclaimer: I have used none of these and do not know if they work for Yarn users.** You should look into other options as well.

I suggest looking into [Pnpm](https://pnpm.io/) as an alternative to Yarn. It supports most of Yarn's features *and* has the `pnpm outdated` command out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

In yarn 4, the `upgrade-interactive` tool comes with the CLI, no need for a plugin.

Simply do

```
yarn upgrade-interactive
```

Answer (score 0):

Must use a plugin https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/tree/master/packages/plugin-interactive-tools:

```
yarn plugin import interactive-tools
yarn upgrade-interactive
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yarn add <package> --interactive` to get an interactive upgrade prompt, which will allow you to select latest from the list.

https://yarnpkg.com/cli/add#details